# Unable to connect to IBM G8000R via serial

Tags: networking, switch, ibm, serial

I have just received a new IBM switch, a G8000R.
It's written on the guide it is necessary to establish a connection between switch and hyperterminal console.
So I have connected the switch via a "Mini USB to Ethernet" adapter (delivered with IBM switch) connected to a serial-ethernet adapter (also delivered with it) to my PC on serial port.

But when I am trying to connect to it via hyperterminal with settings indicated in the guide (9600b), software indicate to me I'm "connected" but nothing appeared... Screen is black.

Do you have an idea to resolve this issue ?

Thx, Sam.

Comment: HyperTerminal will say "Connected" even when there is no actual connection to the device. It is very misleading. Search for an alternative to HyperTerminal, such as [PuTTY](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-serial). I rarely use Windows for my sysadmin duties anymore, but PuTTY used to be one of the top recommended SSH/telnet/Serial clients.

Answer (score 1):

The funny thing about that `connected` status is it doesn’t actually mean it’s connected.

Try to ensure you’re attempting to connect to the correct `COM` port on your local machine.  Realistically, it will be anything other than `COM1` since you’re using an adapter.  A good test to see if anything is making it to your machine is to reboot the G8000 and see if you can see any of the initial self tests showing up on the screen like below.

```
Memory Test ................................
Production Mode
PPCBoot 0.0.0.10 (new flash)
Memory Test (0x00) .............................PASSED 
...
Blade Network Technologies RS 8000 
Jan 1 00:01:27 2008:
NOTICE-5:Interface Oper Status Indication - Port 7 State UP
Password:
```

This will at least let you know if information is making it to the computer.

From the online documentation over at [BladeNetworks](http://www.bladenetwork.net/userfiles/file/PDFs/G8000_install.pdf) about HyperTerminal setup:

```
Use the mini-USB console cable to connect the RS-232 serial port on the switch unit’s front panel to a terminal or a PC running a terminal emulation program. You can access the command-line interface to perform initial configuration tasks. 
The console port’s terminal-emulation requirements are as follows: 
 Default baud rate = 9,600 bps
 Character size = 8 characters
 Parity = none
 Stop bits = 1
 Data bits = 8
 Flow control = none
```

Comment: Hi thx for your answer, I have already done all of it but there is absolutely nothing on the screen during the boot session when serial communication is enabled... I am pretty sure there is a physical problem on the switch.